# 500 server error when adding .htaccess to website

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

My website is hosted on **GoDaddy**. I want to leverage browser caching, so I added an `htaccess` file.

When I do, my site returns 500 error. I deleted the `htaccess` file and my site returns to normal. What am I missing? Here is my `htaccess` file:

```
//Custom 404 errors
ErrorDocument 404 404.php

//Change default directory page
DirectoryIndex index.php

//Prevent viewing of .htaccess file
<Files .htaccess>
    order allow,deny
    deny from all
</Files>

//Prevent directory listings
Options All -Indexes
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: can you show the error message from the server log?

Comment: As stated, check your logs (always!! when dealing with a 500 error) but what I see suspicious here is the use of `404.php` rather than `/404.php`. I think `ErrorDocument` expects web paths to begin with /

Comment: I went to GoDaddy and the ability to turn on error logs isn't present because my client didn't pay for that feature..Oh well. Thanks for your help

Comment: If you can't see logs (which is ridiculous) you have to debug line by line. comment each section out to narrow which is failing. but as noted below, you have `//` comments instead of `#` comments. That is most definitely a syntax error, but maybe not your only error.

Comment: I agree...not paying to see errors is ludicrous. I will try the comments change (I think c# too much)

Comment: Alrighty....i changed my comments and this is the line causing the problem:#Prevent directory listings Options All -Indexes...so i'll google how to fix that. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is this the exact `htaccess` file?

1. You have to display comments with `#` instead of `//`
2. Change `ErrorDocument 404 404.php` to `ErrorDocument 404 /404.php`

Then if problem still exists, try this too:

3. Change `Options All -Indexes` to `IndexIgnore`

Comment: I didn't even notice the comments.

Comment: The problem was the comments and  Options All- Indexes...I changed it to Options - Indexes...It works fine and i added leverage browser caching as well....Thank you